# Control content access in larger Wordpress site using Civicrm credentials

Tags: civimember

We would like to make a portion of our site accessible to members only. Is it possible to tie certain parts of the larger Wordpress site to Civicrm membership?

In otherwords, if a user sets up an account in the Civicrm portion of the site, can that membership be used to access other pages in the site (that are not necessarily within Civicrm?

Comment: It will be good to hear if WP does this. It can be done in Drupal as there is a CiviMember Role Sync module that is part of core

Comment: @petednz WP does this as well, we have Member sync https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-wp-member-sync/ and Profile sync https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-wp-profile-sync/ among others, thanks to Christian Watch and other contributors, which work very well.

Comment: is that different to what i had in my answer, if so i can update it with your links.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google found [this blog](https://civicrm.org/blogs/jag/wordpress-civimember-role-sync-plugin) describing the [CiviMember Role Sync  Plugin for WordPress](https://github.com/jeevajoy/Wordpress-CiviCRM-Member-Role-Sync). Does that deliver what you need?

EDIT - Christian is recommending this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-wp-member-sync/) instead

Comment: The plugin you link to should really be removed from the CiviCRM site - it's an obsolete version of https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-wp-member-sync/

Comment: It looks like that plugin will do what I want. Thank you very much.

Comment: if it is then pls accept the answer as that is how stackexchange works best